# ArcGIS Server proxy settings?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, windows, proxy, configuration

I may be facing a unique issue. My ArcGIS server is running within my company network.The server has picked up the proxy settings of the box it is running in.

But to serve the printing request, the server bypasses this proxy settings and calls url(services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer) directly. As a result this request is getting blocked at the company firewalls and the request is failing. When the firewall was disabled the printing is a success.

I have followed this link 
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000309000000

How do I route all the server requests to the Internet through my proxy server?

I am running ArcGIS 10.1 Server on Windows.

Comment: [DenverCoder9, did you ever find an answer](https://xkcd.com/979/)?

Comment: No I didn't find the answer. I worked with the  network team to temporarily disable the company firewall to get the print done.